# Topologist's Sine Curve Compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $T$= $ \{ (x, \sin(\frac{1}{x}))\in\mathbb R^n \mid x>0 \} \cup \{ (0,y)\in \mathbb R^2\mid y\in[-1,1] \} \subseteq \mathbb R^2$

I've looked through questions regarding the topologist's sine curve and have came across different definitions for various versions of it, so I'm a little confused.

Is this one, $T$, compact?

My guess is yes (because it is closed and bounded? Heine-Borel?), could anyone demonstrate how to prove this?

Comment: If you type a sin b you'll see $a sin b$, but if you type a\sin b you'll see $a\sin b$. The backslash not only de-italicizes $\sin$ but also gives you proper spacing to its left and right. The spacing is context-dependent; for example with a\sin(b) you see $a\sin(b)$ with a smaller space to the right. Similarly \log, \max, \det, \sup, \lim, etc. And $\cup$ is used in $A\cup B$ and $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$, whereas $\bigcup$ is used in things like $\displaystyle\bigcup_{x\in\mathcal X} A_x$. I edited accordingly, and also note my use of \mid. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

The set $\{ (x, \sin(\frac{1}{x}))\in\mathbb R^2 \mid x>0 \} \cup \{ (0,y)\in \mathbb R^2\mid y\in[-1,1] \} \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ is unbounded because the first of the two terms in the union is unbounded.  If instead of $x>0$ you had said $0<x\le 1$, then the union of two sets that you wrote would be closed and bounded; hence compact.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you! So it isn't compact? Could I still use Heine-Borel to prove this?

Comment: Heine–Borel says a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact if and only if it's closed and bounded, so it implies this set is not compact. $\qquad$

Comment: @TamasKantiGarai : Fixed. Thank you. $\qquad$

Comment: How this set is closed?

Comment: @Learner adding the second part of the union, the vertical line segment, gives the closure of the sine curve. Proving this is straightforward in that you only need the tools from elementary topology. If you’re stuck trying to prove it, please post a question asking about it